track volume limit across Mac and iPhone
iPhone has a feature that will track your volume exposure over a 7 day period and warn you if you've been listening at too high volumes for too long of a time over 7 days. They even show you a nifty chart of your listening.
I use my headphones on both my iPhone and my Mac, the latter when streaming video. However as far as I can tell, the two don't work together at all and the Mac may not have this? It seems like kind of an omission for a company that likes making its stuff work together well.
I am just curious if I am missing something and if the two can work together to track this data.
